# Spring - how to enable validation in Web Flow form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I've got some problems with enabling basic validation in Spring Web Flow.

This is how my webflow config class looks like:

```
public class FlowConfiguration extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Validator validator;

    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder()
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            .setFlowBuilderServices(flowBuilderServices())
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
            .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping()
    {
        FlowHandlerMapping fh = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        fh.setFlowRegistry(flowRegistry());
        return fh;
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter()
    {
        FlowHandlerAdapter fh = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        fh.setFlowExecutor(flowExecutor());
        return fh;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices()
    {
        return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
                .setValidator(validator)
                .build();
    }


}
```

I know I have to set validator in `FlowBuilderServices`, however when I do that, I get error (when running webflow):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ElectronicsStore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@6397b3b6 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@7880da33 expression = cartServiceImpl.validate(requestParameters.cartId), resultExpression = order.cart], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'addCartToOrder' of flow 'checkout' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'cartServiceImpl' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
```

This is the code for that view:

```
<action-state id="addCartToOrder">
        <evaluate expression="cartServiceImpl.validate(requestParameters.cartId)"
            result="order.cart" />
```

And everything works fine, but only if I remove `addFlowBuilderServices` method from flow registry. Can you give me any directions how to configure it properly?

I think `FlowBuilderServices` overrides some flow settings, making it impossible to properly parse expressions.

WebConfig.java

```
package godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView;
import org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper;
import godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.domain.Product;

@Configuration
@Import(godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.config.FlowConfiguration.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "godziszewski.patryk")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true); 
    return resolver;
    }

     @Override
        public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {

            UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
            urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);

            configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
        }


    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }




    /*@Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling (
    DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
    }*/
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
    @Bean
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer()
    {
        TilesConfigurer tiles = new TilesConfigurer();
        tiles.setDefinitions(new String[] {
                "/WEB-INF/tiles/definition/tile-definition.xml"
        });
        tiles.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tiles;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver tv = new TilesViewResolver();
        tv.setOrder(-2);
        return  tv;
    }
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource()
    {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rb.setBasename("messages");
        return rb;
    }
    @Bean
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver()
    {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
@Bean
public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentResolver()
{
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver cn = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();


    List<View> listOfViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    listOfViews.add(jsonView());
    listOfViews.add(xmlView());

    cn.setDefaultViews(listOfViews);


    return cn;
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2JsonView jsonView()
{
    MappingJackson2JsonView mj= new MappingJackson2JsonView();
    mj.setPrettyPrint(true);
    return mj;
}



@Bean
public MarshallingView xmlView()
{
    Jaxb2Marshaller ja = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    ja.setClassesToBeBound(Product.class);

    MarshallingView mv = new MarshallingView(ja);

    return mv;
}
@Bean
public Validator validator()
{
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean lv = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    lv.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return lv;
}

}
```

Comment: Name of your bean `cartServiceImpl` or `cartService`?

Comment: CartServiceImpl class is annotated with @Service annotation (so bean name is by default cartServiceImpl), it implements CartService interface. As I said, everything works fine as it is if i remove flowBuilderServices from config ( but I can't use validation then)

Comment: Can you post the class that inherits from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`?. Be sure to be overriding the `getValidator()` method. Remember SWF uses Spring MVC infrastructure, for example about formatters and in this case from Validation. Is very important the `getValidator()` method.

Comment: I updated the post